# How to get idle time in Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm creating a Password Manager, and as a security feature I wanted to add session time that logs the user out after some time of inactivity (in the example code 3 seconds), and I have this code :

```
import os
import time
import threading

# Checks what OS you're using
def check_platform():
    if os.name == "nt":
        platform = "Windows"
    else:
        platform = "Linux"
    return platform


# Starts inactivity timer
def start_timer():
    platform = check_platform()
    if platform == "Windows":
        def timer_start():
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                check_if_idle_windows()
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=timer_start)
        thread1.start()
    elif platform == "Linux":
        def timer_start():
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                check_if_idle_linux()
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=timer_start)
        thread1.start()


# Checks if the user is idle on Windows
def check_if_idle_windows():
    import win32api
    idle_time = (win32api.GetTickCount() - win32api.GetLastInputInfo()) / 1000.0
    if idle_time > 3:
        os.system("cls")
        print("You have been logged out due to inactivity.")
        os._exit(0)


# Checks if the user is idle on Linux
def check_if_idle_linux():
    ### Code to get idle time here ###
    if idle_time > 3:
        os.system("clear")
        print("You have been logged out due to inactivity.")
        os._exit(0)


def random_function_for_main_thread():
    while True:
        my_string = input("Enter something or stay inactive for 3 seconds : ")
        print("You entered something.")


def main():
    start_timer()
    random_function_for_main_thread()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What can I use to get idle time on Linux?
I tried [this](https://pypi.org/project/idle-time/) and [this](https://pypi.org/project/idleTime/), and neither of them worked.
Hope my question isn't repeated, thank you.

Comment: It would irritate me to no end if my password manager logged me out for inactivity.  ALL of the operating systems have the ability to lock the desktop after an idle period.  Why aren't you just using that?

Comment: @TimRoberts my major is Cyber Security, and my professor focuses on security features and asked me to implement this feature.
Because if for some reason you were away from your computer you don't want anyone walking by to see your passwords.

Comment: @TimRoberts 
P.S. : As Cyber Security students we're taught that we can't rely on the knowledge/ignorance of the users, we always have to assume that the user has no knowledge of security.

Comment: @Osama A. Al-Amarneh: What's wrong with the second link you posted. It uses [xprintidle](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xprintidle.1.html), which seems feasible to use.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I used `import idle

print(idle.get_idle_duration())` which was mentioned in their [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/idleTime/), it would give me no module named idle error.
However I tried `subprocess.getoutput('xprintidle')` and it worked fine, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import time
import threading


# Starts inactivity timer
def start_timer():
    platform = check_platform()
    if platform == "Windows":
        def timer_start():
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                check_if_idle_windows()
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=timer_start)
        thread1.start()

    elif platform == "Linux":
        def timer_start():
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                check_if_idle_linux()
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=timer_start)
        thread1.start()


# Checks what OS you're using
def check_platform():
    if os.name == "nt":
        platform = "Windows"
    else:
        platform = "Linux"
    return platform


# Checks if the user is idle on Windows
def check_if_idle_windows():
    import win32api
    idle_time = (win32api.GetTickCount() - win32api.GetLastInputInfo()) / 1000.0
    if idle_time > 3:
        os.system("cls")
        print("You have been logged out due to inactivity.")
        os._exit(0)


# Checks if the user is idle on Linux
def check_if_idle_linux():
    import subprocess
    idle_time = int(subprocess.getoutput('xprintidle')) / 1000 # Requires xprintidle (sudo apt install xprintidle)
    if idle_time > 3:
        os.system("clear")
        print("You have been logged out due to inactivity.")
        os._exit(0)


def random_function_for_main_thread():
    while True:
        my_string = input("Enter something or stay inactive for 3 seconds : ")
        print("You entered something.")


def main():
    start_timer()
    random_function_for_main_thread()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```